# Why aren't some of my css pages being used?

Tags: css, ftp, media, tablet, cloudflare

Both of my last 2 css pages (800px.css and 800pxland.css) are being neglected in rendering my website on a tablet device. I cannot figure out why, all of the other ones work just fine. As a matter of fact, they worked just hours ago but now no matter what I change and to what degree I change it, nothing works. I just started using Bluehost's CloudFlare service so I'm not sure if that has something to do with it (yes, I am FTP'ing while in dev. mode on CloudFlare). I have been using google chrome as my browser on the tablet the whole time. Ill get the  posted p and hopefully it'll help. Thanks!

```
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="public">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Fri, 30 Dec 2022 12:00:00 GMT">
<title>About EDM Uncovered</title>
<link href="/css/12gs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Autour+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura:400,600,500,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Days+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="/jquery/jQuery.ui.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/protoFluid3.02.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/unslider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/active.js"></script>
<link media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/css/480px.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link media="screen and (max-device-width:600px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="/css/480pxland.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link media="screen and (min-device-width: 1300px) and (max-device-width: 1399px)" href="/css/1300px.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link media="screen and (min-device-width: 1400px)" href="/css/1400px.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link media="screen and (min-device-width:601px) and (max-device-width:800px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="/css/800px.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link media="screen and (min-device-width:800px) and (max-device-width:1300px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="/css/800pxland.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <html lang="en" class="ie8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>   
    <html lang="en" class="ie9">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie9.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><!--<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

> As a matter of fact, they worked just hours ago...

If by this you mean that the 2 ipad CSS stylesheets were working and now they aren't, then to me it's implying either an issue with them being cached via CloudFlare or there's a CSS error on the stylesheets or styles from another stylesheet are taking precedent.

You could test each possibility by

- save duplicates of the last 2 stlyesheets and update the HTML accordingly
  eg `<link media="screen and (min-device-width:601px) and (max-device-width:800px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="/css/800px-alt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` . This would rule out a caching issue
- validate the last 2 stylesheets @ [W3 CSS validation](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input)
- add a new test selector on each of the last 2 stylesheets and see if you can get it to stick, eg `body{background-color:green !important;`

These are the most likely causes that come to mind for me.

Good luck!

`